# Lombok builder Warning - initializing expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have this POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
        })
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String username;

}
```

but I have this warning and I don't know how to fix it

```
 @Builder will ignore the initializing expression entirely. If you want the initializing expression to serve as default, add @Builder.Default. If it is not supposed to be settable during building, make the field final.
```

Comment: Maybe add `@Builder.Default` to the `id` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lombok.Data` Is a better to use annotation for `@Entity` classes. It gives you `@Getter`, `@Setter` and `@NoArgsConstructor` which is exactly what JPA needs.